# Do member variables of an Activity retain values after onResume?

Tags: android

Is this safe to assume that when onResume is called all of the member variables native or objects in the activity are still valid ?

In otherwords is it possible that android cleans up any member of an activity under memory stress conditions and then ends up calling onResume ?

Answer (score 1):

When onResume is called anything that was previously set in onCreate, onStart, etc will be there.  However if the Activity is deleted due to memory pressure you may have to recreate old values in either onRestoreInstanceState or onCreate, either of which will be called again before onResume is.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the activity lifecycle guarantees the state will remain on calling onResume. The documentation states that you should reinitialise all components in onPause

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html#Resume

An excerpt from the above link:

When the user resumes your activity from the Paused state, the system calls the onResume() method.

Be aware that the system calls this method every time your activity comes into the foreground, including when it's created for the first time
As such, you should implement onResume() to initialize components that you release during onPause() and perform any other initializations that must occur each time the activity enters the Resumed state (such as begin animations and initialize components only used while the activity has user focus).

Comment: You should not be intitializing anyhting in onPause.  You should be releasing system resources.  However you can assume that by the time onResume is called that other initialization steps have already been called.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: I meant onResume not onPause